Definite integral $\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sin 2x+ \cos 2x}dx $
I am trying to evaluate the integral
$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sin 2x+ \cos 2x}dx
$$
Although it appears normal, I have trouble solving it. I tried the standard half angle substitution $t=\tan\frac x2$ for the trigonometric integrand, which resulted in a high order rational function and I was unable to reduce it. I would like to know how to proceed, or find out other ways to tackle the integral.

Have you tried the substitution $ t=\frac \pi 4-x$

Use kings rule.

This isn't as easy as it looks... traditional methods fail after kings rule ....i strongly believe that it has something to do with beta functions

Shift the integration to the symmetric domain $(-\frac\pi8,\frac\pi8)$ with the variable change $x=t+\frac\pi8$ and drop the odd part of the resulting integrand, i.e.
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sin 2x+ \cos 2x}
\overset{x=t+\frac\pi8}{dx}\\
=&\ \cos\frac\pi8 \int_{-\pi/8}^{\pi/8} \frac{\cos t}{ \cos 2t}dt
= 2 \cos\frac\pi8 \int_{0}^{\pi/8} \frac{d(\sin t) }{ 1-2\sin^2 t}\\
=&\ \sqrt{1+\frac1{\sqrt2}} \tanh^{-1} \sqrt{1-\frac1{\sqrt2}}
\end{align}

This can also be done like
$$\int_0^\fracπ4 \frac{\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt 2}+\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt 2}}{\frac{\sin 2x}{\sqrt 2}+\frac{\cos 2x}{\sqrt 2}}dx\\
\implies \int_0^\fracπ4 \frac{\sin(x+\frac{π}{4})}{\sin(2x+\frac{π}{4})}dx $$
Take $2x+\fracπ4=u\implies du=2dx$
$$\implies \int_\fracπ4^\frac{3π}{4} \frac{\sin(\frac{u}{2}+\frac{π}{8})}{2\sin u}du= \int_\fracπ4^\frac{3π}{4} \frac{(\sin\frac{u}{2}\cos\frac{π}{8}+\cos\frac{u}{2}\sin\frac{π}{8})}{4\sin \frac{u}{2} \cos \frac{u}{2}}du$$
$$\frac14\int_\fracπ4^\frac{3π}{4}\cos\fracπ8\sec \frac{u}{2}+\sin\fracπ8\csc\frac{u}{2} du$$
You can continue on your own from here :)

Hint:
Like Evaluate the integral $\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 \frac{\sin^3x}{\sin^3x+\cos^3x}\,\mathrm dx$.,
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/4}\dfrac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sin2x+\cos2x}\ dx=\int_0^{\pi/4}\dfrac{\sqrt2\cos x}{\cos2x+\sin2x}\ dx$$
$$I+I=?$$
Now setting $\dfrac\pi4=2y,\sqrt2+1=\csc2y+\cot2y=\cdots=\cot y$
$\implies (\sqrt2+1)\cos x+\sin x=\cot y\cos x+\sin x=\dfrac{\cos\left(x-y\right)}{\sin y}$
$$\sin2x+\cos2x=\sqrt2\cos2\left(x-y\right)=\sqrt2\left(2\cos^2(x-y)-1\right)$$
Use Ways to evaluate $\int \sec \theta \, \mathrm d \theta$

I’m getting $\int_0^{\pi/4}\dfrac{\sqrt2\cos x}{\cos2x+\sin2x}\ dx$ instead of $\int_0^{\pi/4}\dfrac{\sqrt2\sin x}{\cos2x+\sin2x}\ dx$.

@Aig same here.

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad, Thanks for your observation

Let $x=\arctan y=\arctan\dfrac{1-z^2}{2z}$ (i.e. Euler substitution):
$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^\tfrac\pi4 \frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sin(2x)+\cos(2x)} \, dx \\
&= \sqrt2 \int_0^1 \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1+y^2} \left(1+2y-y^2\right)} \\
&= \frac12 \int_0^1 \left(\frac1{1+\sqrt2-y} - \frac1{1-\sqrt2-y}\right) \, \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1+y^2}} \\
&= \int_{\sqrt2-1}^1 \left(\frac1{1+2\left(\sqrt2-1\right)z-z^2} - \frac1{1-2\left(\sqrt2+1\right)z-z^2}\right) \, dz 
\end{align*}$$
Can you continue from here?

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{\pi/4}\dfrac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sin2x+\cos2x}\ dx\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/4}\dfrac{\sqrt2\cos x}{\cos2x+\sin2x}\ dx \tag{King’s rule}\\
&=\frac12 \int_0^{\pi/4}\dfrac{\sin x+(1+\sqrt2)\cos x}{\cos2x+\sin2x}\ dx\tag{$I=\frac{I+I}2$}\\
&= \frac12 \int_0^{\pi/4}\dfrac{\sin x+\cot\frac\pi8\cdot\cos x}{\cos2x+\sin2x}\ dx\\
&= \frac1{2\sin\frac\pi8} \int_0^{\pi/4}\dfrac{\cos (x-\frac\pi8)}{\cos2x+\sin2x}\ dx\\
&= \frac1{2\sin\frac\pi8} \int_0^{\pi/4}\dfrac{\cos (x-\frac\pi8)}{\sqrt2\cos(2x-\frac\pi4)}\ dx\\
&= \frac1{2\sqrt2\sin\frac\pi8} \int_0^{\pi/4}\dfrac{\cos (x-\frac\pi8)}{\cos(2(x-\frac\pi8))}\ d(x-\frac\pi8)\\
&= \frac1{2\sqrt2\sin\frac\pi8} \int_{-\pi/8}^{\pi/8}\dfrac{\cos x}{\cos2x}\ dx\tag{$x-\frac\pi8\to x $}\\
&= \frac1{2\sqrt2\sin\frac\pi8} \int_{-\pi/8}^{\pi/8}\dfrac{\cos x}{(\cos x+\sin x) (\cos x-\sin x)}\ dx\\
&= \frac1{4\sqrt2\sin\frac\pi8} \int_{-\pi/8}^{\pi/8}\left(\dfrac{1}{\cos x+\sin x}+\frac1{\cos x-\sin x}\right)\ dx\\
&= \frac1{2\sqrt2\sin\frac\pi8} \int_{-\pi/8}^{\pi/8}\dfrac{1}{\cos x+\sin x}\ dx\tag{symmetry}\\
&= \frac1{4\sin\frac\pi8} \int_{-\pi/8}^{\pi/8}\dfrac{1}{\sin (x+\frac\pi4)}\ dx\\
&= \frac1{4\sin\frac\pi8} \ln \left| \tan \left( \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{x+\frac\pi4}{2} \right) \right|\bigg|_{-\pi/8}^{\pi/8}\\
&= \frac1{4\sin\frac\pi8} \ln \left|\frac{ \tan \left( \frac{7\pi}{16} \right)}{\tan \left( \frac{5\pi}{16} \right)}\right|\\
&\approx0.791575
.\end{align}$$
Also, $$I= \frac1{4\sin\frac\pi8} \ln \left|\frac{ \tan \left( \frac{7\pi}{16} \right)}{\tan \left( \frac{5\pi}{16} \right)}\right|=\frac{\ln (-1+2\sqrt2+2\sqrt{2-\sqrt2})}{2\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}}.$$
